# How to hide classes (from a referenced C# DLL) marked with "internal" keyword in intellisense in monodevelop?

Tags: c#, dll, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, internal

I'm referencing an external C# DLL with a number of classes marked with the "internal" keyword in a monotouch project. However, monodevelop's intellisense shows all of the classes regardless if they are marked with "internal" keyword or not. If I reference this assembly in VS2010 only unmarked classes are shown. How can I get the same behaviour (hide all internal classes) in monodevelop?

I already checked "InternalsVisibleTo" attribute, but it seems to be irrelevant here. Also i couldn't use the EditorBrowsable Attribute as i need to hide the entire class.